# Can we install SQL server 2000 on SBS 2011

Tags: sql-server

Iwould like to install sql server 2000 on server sbs 2011.
Could you please show me the way.because i have a last database on sql 2000.

Answer (score 6):

SBS 2011 is based on Server 2008. [Server 2008 is not a supported platform for SQL Server 2000.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028963).